# Navigation Bar is overlapping with another View Controller's Navigation Bar in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

The minimum version of the app is set on iOS 7. However the testing device I have is on iOS 9. Since the XCode 7 is unable to run iOS7 simulators, I ahve no way to test my app on iOS7.
The remote testing team however is testing on iOS 7 and they reported this issue in following screenshot -

[image: Overlap]

This is happening at multiple places. This happens only when I perform a push segue (already defined in storyboard). I am unable to reproduce this issue in iOS9. I couldn't check in iOS8 since my simulator is acting weird.

So how can I find the exact reason of this strange behavior? Why does it happen at the first place? Am I doing something wrong? And finally, how can I debug it without needing an actual iOS7 device?

**Update:**
I tried the following lines in the `viewDidLoad`

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

But it still didn't work. I am using Crashlytics and found a particular issue as most relevant to this. Here's the link for this

> [The crash Log](http://crashes.to/s/f3ae8a885a5)

And here's the excerpt

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Can't add self as subview
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x30b42f83 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b2f3ccf objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x30b42ec5 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  UIKit                          0x3336b535 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
4  UIKit                          0x3336b4bf -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:]
5  UIKit                          0x33533f71 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke
6  UIKit                          0x33371ac5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
7  UIKit                          0x33533879 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]
8  UIKit                          0x334f0b27 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
9  UIKit                          0x3340dd63 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:]
10 UIKit                          0x3340db6d -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]
11 UIKit                          0x3340db05 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
12 UIKit                          0x3335fd59 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
13 QuartzCore                     0x32fdd62b -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
14 QuartzCore                     0x32fd8e3b CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
15 QuartzCore                     0x32fd8ccd CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
16 QuartzCore                     0x32fd86df CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
17 QuartzCore                     0x32fd84ef CA::Transaction::commit()
18 QuartzCore                     0x32fd221d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
19 CoreFoundation                 0x30b0e255 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
20 CoreFoundation                 0x30b0bbf9 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
21 CoreFoundation                 0x30b0bf3b __CFRunLoopRun
22 CoreFoundation                 0x30a76ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific
23 CoreFoundation                 0x30a76ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode
24 GraphicsServices               0x3597c663 GSEventRunModal
25 UIKit                          0x333c314d UIApplicationMain
26 Palscom                        0xf1463 main (main.m:14)
27 libdyld.dylib                  0x3b800ab7 start
```

Do they look related? If they are what could be the reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

set

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

in  viewDidLoad and then check

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping navigation bar color is translucent, Setting it to a solid color fixes the problem